# Plone 4 removes html attributes from a script tag no matter what

Tags: html, plone

I've disabled the safe_html portal transform completely (/portal_transforms/safe_html/manage_main), as well turned off all the filtering in the html filtering control panel (/@@filter-controlpanel).

But still, if I try to enter something like this into the tinymce editor html view:

```
<script type="IN/MemberProfile" data-id="http://www.linkedin.com/in/mostmedia" data-format="inline"></script>
```

After saving it becomes:

```
<script type="IN/MemberProfile"></script>
```

Is there anyplace else I should be looking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding `<script />` tags in TinyMCE with all attributes intact works for me on a fresh Plone 4.3.2 site if I do the following:

1. Go to `/portal_transforms/safe_html/manage_main`.
2. Remove `script` from `nasty_tags`.
3. Add `script` to `valid_tags`.
4. Restart Zope to clear the object cache.

Comment: I did the script bit earlier. But, I am using an older  version of plone, just 4.0.  I'll try upgrading and will check back. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, with Plone 4.3.2 the tags aren't stripped.  It would be time to upgrade only the linkedin profile plugin seems totally broken!